# Does anyone know how to grant permissions on Azure DevOps to azure data factory?

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-devops, devops, azure-data-factory

Does anyone know how to grant permissions on Azure DevOps to an MSP01(secondary) account or by using PAT token?

I need to integrate Azure data factory with GIT repo. But in Azure DevOps we use our company domain account and if I add the MSP01 account directly they are managed as "external" accounts and they will have restricted access to the project.

So is there a way to connect to azure DevOps from azure data factory using PAT token??

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> So is there a way to connect to azure DevOps from azure data factory using PAT token?

I am afraid there is no such a way to connect to azure DevOps from azure data factory using PAT token at this moment.

[image]

To resolve this issue, you could try to add those "external" users as guest in AAD to get access to the Azure devops.

You could check [this similar thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/365891/ability-to-link-vsts-to-multiple-azure-active-dire.html) and [the document](https://medium.com/@cprosenjit/azure-devops-pipeline-setup-for-azure-data-factory-v2-8e957cd5141) for some details.

Hope this helps.